# current location dot and destination are far away for iphone

Tags: iphone

is it possible to adjust map so that it can show both current and destination point 
right now if my destination is far then i can only see detination but not current and if they are close then i can see both

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can adjust the zoom level of the map. You will need to perform your own calculations to determine if both the destination and current locations are within the current view. But the map zoom level is what you can set.

Comment: but how to calculate the distance between current and destination

Comment: There are several ways: geospatial functions, haversine calculations, etc. I suggest searching/asking that as a different question.